# Will one LED blowing make entire LED strip stop working?

Tags: led-strip

I am trying to understand how LEDs are connected together to power source on an LED strip. LED strips can be cut at designated points on the strip to create a shorter strip.

I believe that an LED strip contains only LED and resistors, there is no other active or passive component on LED strips by default. Now the question is, how are these LEDs connected to the power source. If one of these LEDs blows and becomes open circuit, what will happen to the rest of the LEDs before and after this one on the strip? Will all of them stop working or just some of them?

Comment: Learn about *series* and *parallel* connections. Hint: if you can cut the strip and it still works, would a single faulty LED cause the whole strip to fail?

Comment: I don't know, this is why I am asking here. I need to install LED strip light into my gaden shed. I have figured out that I need solar panel, battery charge controller, battery charger, LED dimmer, LED strip. However, a few questions still remain. Why not ask someone on the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the LED strip, but if it has cuttable points then one dead LED won't cause the remainder of the strip to go out.

If you can see a cut point after each LED, then the LEDs will be hooked up like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY8Ijy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All of the LEDs are effectively in parallel, so if one LED blows then the rest continue working just fine.

Commonly, in LED strips that use 12V supplies, you'll find that there cut points every 3 or 4 LEDs. That's because the forward voltage drop of each LED is only a few volts, so it makes more sense to run a few LEDs in series and make the most out of the 12V supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5ZQML.png)</sup>

In this case, if one of the LEDs in a series set breaks, then the others in that set will stop working too. All the other LEDs will continue to work just fine, though, because they're effectively in parallel with the failed LED.

With individually addressable LEDs, it depends on the design. With WS2812B each LED has a data in pin and a data out pin. If one of the LEDs on the strip fails, it may stop transmitting data forward, causing the remainder of the strip to fail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYcAN3.png)</sup>

There are addressable LED types that attempt to avoid this problem, such as WS2813, which as a backup input (BI), but that's going a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

LEDs are solid state devices and unlikely to burn out.   Some people think that because all light emitters *up to now* have burned out and are socketed for that reason. (Well, not neon). Fair assumption, but wrong.

However if one did fail, it would only break the section in between the "cut" lines.